# Ratchet straps — Purpose of 15-inch loops

Tags: gear, ropes, storage

I have a set of [Rhino 1-inch ratchet straps](https://www.amazon.ca/gp/product/B07K3QD3JL/ref=ppx_yo_dt_b_search_asin_title?ie=UTF8&th=1). The straps came with separate 15-inch loop straps:

[image]

What is the purpose of the loop straps?

And why do they have a *twist* in them? They aren't sewn with a simple fold at the one end; they're shaped more like a *Mobius strip* (but with a seam in the middle).

Comment: I'd guess that they're to act as a handle for pulling - the twist will hold that loop a bit more open. But not knowing what else you've got, I don't know what the other half would attach to

Comment: Twists are also useful when attaching loads to road vehicles - they reduce the likelihood of resonant vibration at speed.  I always put a twist in my loops for this reason.

Comment: And they can make it easier to get your fingers in when the loop is pulled tight.

Comment: If you can't hook the ends of the rachet strap directly to some anchor point, you can use the straps to create an eye to hook the strap's hook into.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

They are designed to be girth hitched to create attachment points for the S clips. NRS has a [similar product](https://www.nrs.com/nrs-1-loop-straps/pkvc) but with different attachment style which shows the configuration well:

[image]

It allows for semi-permanent attachment of the straps to crossbars or rails making it faster (in some cases) to tie things down. The twist helps the girth hitch to sit flush.